# Play authenticate plugin - providers

Tags: java, authentication, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play authenticate plugin but I have no foggiest idea how to provide custom authentication with login & password. I.e. before I've started using the plugin I'd built up the whole authentication module and I would like to incorporate it into the plugin.

There's neither any documentation nor tutorial on this subject and I don't really understand 
how the sample code works:
https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/providers

My goal is just to check if provided login & password are matching one of entries in database, using previously written methods. Please, help me.